# Is $\lim_{x\to0}x^{p}\int^{x}_1w^{-p}f\left(w\right)dw = 0$?

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

Is it true
$$\lim_{x\to+0}x^{p}\int^{x}_1w^{-p}f\left(w\right)dw=0,$$
where $f\in C^{0}(\mathbb{R})$, and $p>0$?

In a case $f$ is an analytic, this relation can be easily proved by decomposing $f$ into Taylor series. 
Another way is integration by parts, but this also requires the function $f$ to be at least $\left\lfloor p\right\rfloor$  times differentiable.
But how to prove if $f$ is just bounded?

Comment: What is the lower limit of the integral?

Comment: Does $C^0$ denote continuous functions that vanish at infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is bounded, there is an $M$ such that $|f(x)| \le M$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then
$$
\left|x^p\int_x^1 w^{-p}f(w)dw\right|\le x^p\int_x^1 \left|w^{-p}f(w)\right|dw \le  x^p\int_x^1  M w^{-p} dw .
$$
This integral can be evaluated, giving
$$
x^p\int_x^1  M w^{-p} dw  =\begin{cases}Mx^p \frac{1-x^{1-p}}{1-p} & 0<p<1 \\ Mx \ln(x) & p = 1 \\ Mx\frac{1-x^{p-1}}{p-1} & p>1\end{cases}.
$$
Since all three of those clearly go to zero as $x \rightarrow 0^+$, and they bound the magnitude of the original integral, it must also go to zero.

Comment: I think you lost a $-$ from the $w^{p}$.

Comment: @Botond Minus signs are wily creatures.